# スペースの入った行をスペース以外の区切り文字で分割してコマンド引数に渡したい

Tags: shellscript

`:` で区切られたファイル(`/etc/passwd`)の各行から 6列目の値 (= home directory) を取り出して、
以下のようにコマンドに渡したいです。

**/etc/passwd**

```
sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
ec2-user:x:1000:1000:EC2 Default User:/home/ec2-user:/bin/bash
```

**実行したいコマンド**

```
command /var/empty/sshd /home/ec2-user
```

`split` 系の記事を見るとどれも `tr ',' '\n'` でスペースに分けてゴニョゴニョするものばかりなので、元々スペースを含むファイルだとうまく行きません。

Python や Ruby のワンライナーを使ってしまえば簡単なんですが、プロビジョニングに使いたいのでそれらがインストールされてないサーバーにも適用したく、できれば基本コマンドだけで実現する方法はないでしょうか。

Comment: `cut -d: -f6 /etc/passwd | xargs command` などという方法もあります。

Comment: 対象を `/etc/passwd` ファイルに限定するのであれば区切り文字は `:` (セミコロン) と決まっているので、タイトルもその様に書いた方がやりたい事が伝わりやすいかと。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「基本コマンド」ってどのへんまでを想定しているのかわからなかったのですが、
awkとxargsを使えば次のようになります。
(とりあえず「echo」を付けましたがcommandを直接実行するなら「echo」は外してください)

```
$ awk -F: '{print $6}' /etc/passwd | xargs echo command
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！　管理対象で awk, xargs は普通に使え増田。レシピにするときに１行コマンドの方が見やすいので使わせていただきます

Answer (score 3):

シェルスクリプトで実現するならば、
シェル変数「`IFS`」を「`:`」にすることで、「`:`」を区切り文字として`read`で各フィールドを読み込めると思います。

```
# 例
cat /etc/passwd | while IFS=: read user x uid gid username homedir loginshell ; do
    # 第6フィールドの値をcommandに渡す
    command "${homedir}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

6番目のフィールドを${command}に渡すスクリプトです。user20098さんのコードを参考にしました。

【スクリプト】

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=":"
cat /etc/passwd | while read line; do
    set ${line}
    ${command} ${6}
done
```

【使用例:echo コマンドを実行する場合】

```
command=echo スクリプト
```

---

ファイル、区切り記号、フィールドを外から指定可能にしてみました。

【スクリプトその２】

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS="${delimiter}"
cat ${file} | while read line; do
    set ${line}
    eval ${command}
done
```

【使用例】

```
command='printf "home=%s\n" $6' delimiter=: file=/etc/passwd ./スクリプトその２
```

Answer (score 0):

既出ですが、 `awk` ですね。

```sh
$ cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{ print "command",$6,$7 }'
command /var/empty/sshd /sbin/nologin
command /home/ec2-user /bin/bash
```